# MD5 decrypt script

Tags: python

```
__author__ = 'Zane'
import hashlib
import sys

if (len(sys.argv)!=2 ) or (len(sys.argv[1])!= 32):

    print("[---] md5cracker.py & hash")
    sys.exit(1)


    crackedmd5 = sys.argv[1]

    # open a file and read its contents

    f = open('file.txt')

    lines = f.readline()

    f.close()


    for line in lines:

        cleanline = line.rstrip()

        hashobject = hashlib.md5(cleanline)

        if (hashobject==crackedmd5):

            print('Plain text password for ' + crackedmd5 + "is "  + hashobject + '\n')
```

I get no error with exit code 1 and i do not know where i get it wrong

Comment: oh where did my text go! ok basically i want to decrypt md5 hash to plain text, so inside file.txt file i have list of plain text passwords. new to python as student i need a bit help on where i get it wrong :) much appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pythons code structure is based on indent of lines. For now your whole code is part of the `if (len(sys.argv)!=2 ) or (len(sys.argv[1])!= 32):` condition.

You need to unindent all lines with one tab starting from `crackedmd5 = sys.argv[1]`

---

#### EDIT

You also used `lines = f.readline()` which will read only one line and so `for line in lines` will iterate over every single char in that line and not over multiple lines. You need to use `lines = f.readlines()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your replys .  I still get no output? not sure if i got the logic correct or not!

Answer (score 2):

Your program exits with status code one because you told it so (roughly on line 8):

```
sys.exit(1)
```